# Azure ARM template concat with resourceId

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

Hi I am working in Azure ARM template. I am trying to get app url and add some string at the end.

```
 {
   "name": "HealthCheck__SwaggerUrl",
   "value": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameApi'), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName), '/swagger/v1/swagger.json']"
 }
```

I am trying to get app service url and append /swagger/v1/swagger.json. Above statement gives me error

```
Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression 'concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameApi'), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName), '/swagger/v1/swagger.json'': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Comma'.'.
```

I am not able to get the root cause of this issue. Can someone help me to identify the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It looks to me like you have a closing bracket in the wrong place and`.defaultHostName), '/swagger/v1/swagger.json']` should be `.defaultHostName, '/swagger/v1/swagger.json')]`.

Comment: Thanks Connell. I changed but I am getting error Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression 'resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameApi'), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName, '/swagger/v1/swagger.json'': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Comma'.'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to use `reference`.

```
 {
   "name": "HealthCheck__SwaggerUrl",
   "value": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameApi')), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName, '/swagger/v1/swagger.json')]"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stringfellow. I added above piece of line but started getting error Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression 'concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceNameApi')), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName), '/swagger/v1/swagger.json'': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Comma'.'.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. I didn't catch the parenthesis position for the `concat` operator.

Comment: syntax error went but started getting Deployment template validation failed: 'Circular dependency detected on resource: '/subscriptions/--/resourceGroups/RGDEVDVLGENSEAWE01/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/WADEVDVLGENSEAWE02-WebApi'

Comment: Looks like we need to create child resource for configurations then we need to reference paraent resource using dependson. because in in the above code name of app service is variables('appServiceNameApi') and same thing I am referencing inside config. We may need to config as separate resource using Microsoft.Web/sites/config